# "Respect for your privacy" vs "Respecting your privacy"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, sentence-construction, difference

[**Source**](https://blog.whatsapp.com/529/Setting-the-record-straight)

Is there a difference between saying:

> Respect for your privacy is coded into our DNA ...

Or

> Respecting your privacy is coded into our DNA ...

Thanks!

Comment: @MEhsan Please give us more context. Do you think _Respecting_ has a different meaning than _Respect for_ in the sentence? If so, why do you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They give the same idea.

> (To have/show/maintain) respect for your privacy is the way we function.
>
> (The practice of) respecting your privacy is the way we function.